# Ubuntu Memory Error Python Processed Killed However, it's using 5% of RAM According to HTOP

Tags: python, linux, pandas

I've kept an eye on HTOP whilst my python script runs. It's hitting 400mb tops out of an available 8gb.

The script is storing around 400k rows (20 cols) of data into an Sqlite db via pandas.

It runs fine on my local machine (also 8GB of ram, windows).

The error in the logs is "Out of memory: kill process".

I've used memory profiler to reduce memory usage however, it feels like it's vein considering it's running fine on my laptop and only hitting 400mb.

```py
#where it's dying

df = pd.read_csv(reports_directory+'/download.csv', encoding="utf-8")
df.to_sql(report_name.lower(), db.conn, index=False, if_exists="replace")
```

Comment: Can you post the entire script? Also, is the sqlite db in memory of the same machine as well?

Comment: I honestly don't know how much more I can add beyond what's in the OP. 

The thing I don't understand is, how can HTOP say I'm using 400mb but the script die due to using too much RAM?